# Do stuff in a component that renders a flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Post component that I use to render posts in a FlatList. Right now the component is only rendering text and images to the Flatlist, but in the Post component, there are buttons that should do things like deleting, opening a new screen etc. based on the functions which are again based on the information from the specified item in the FlatList that is clicked.

A part of my app.js

```
  deletePost = (author) => {
    alert("Deleted post by" + author)
  }
  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <Post
        author={item.user}
      />
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <FlatList data={this.state.getData} renderItem={this.renderItem}>
     </FlatList>
    )
  }
```

This is the component

```
const Post = (props) => {
  return (   
          <Text onPress={() => props.delete(props.author)}>
            <Icon />
          </Text>
  )
}
```

This is where I am stuck. I get the alert, but the author is rendered as undefined.

Comment: You're asking why in alert `author===undefined` or what?

Comment: @Papi Yes, how can I make it to be ´item.user´

Comment: Pass the arg to the function :) See my answer for more description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question specified in the comment, you should pass the arg to the function, like:

```
deletePost = (author) => {
  alert("Deleted post by" + author)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved it. Didn't know it where this easy.

Comment: @vemund, then you should consider accepting this answer to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it would help you. Please try it as following:

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <Post
      author={item.user}
      delete={this.deletePost}
    />
  )
}
```

Also deletePost method should be as below.

```
deletePost = (author) => {
  alert("Deleted post by" + author)
}
```